# Angular CLI Build Error When Using Angular Library

Tags: angular

I built an Angular Library and put it on NPM using [this article](https://medium.com/@ngl817/building-an-angular-4-component-library-with-the-angular-cli-and-ng-packagr-53b2ade0701e) as a guide.

Basically, I make a project using the Angular CLI, then use [ng-packagr](https://npmjs.org/ng-packagr) to package it up and put it on NPM. It all seems to work, and does work during development mode in the Angular app that includes the package, but an error occurs when using `ng build --prod`. Here is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

I'm not sure where to go from here on packaging up my library so that it'll work when doing production builds inside other apps. Any suggestions?

To reproduce, generate a new app with the Angular CLI, run `npm install angular-tag-select`, import the `TagSelectModule` from the package, and put it in the imports array of the `AppModule`. Then run `ng build --prod`.

### ** Edit **

[Here's the repo](https://github.com/pjlamb12/angular-tag-select) for the angular-tag-select module.

Comment: Show us your module code.

Comment: @SonuKapoor I edited the original question with a link to the repo for the module.

Comment: Any update on your question ? Did you solve your issue ?